# GridView update function isn't working - does not update records

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, gridview

I created an web application and include a GridView that will retrieve records from a table `testtable`.

The code is as follows:

```
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="product_no" HeaderText="product_no" 
                        InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="product_no" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="product_name" HeaderText="product_name" 
                        SortExpression="product_name" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="price" HeaderText="price" SortExpression="price" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="expire_date" HeaderText="expire_date" 
                        SortExpression="expire_date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="expire_time" HeaderText="expire_time" 
                        SortExpression="expire_time" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>

            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testbaseConnectionString %>" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM testtable WHERE (product_no = @product_no)" 
                InsertCommand="INSERT INTO testtable(product_name, price, expire_date, expire_time) VALUES (@product_name, @price, @expire_date, @expire_time)" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT testtable.* FROM testtable" 
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE testtable SET product_name = @product_name, price = @price, expire_date = @expire_date, expire_time = @expire_time WHERE (product_no = @product_no)">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="product_no" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <InsertParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="product_name" />
                </InsertParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="product_name" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="price" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="expire_date" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="expire_time" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="product_no" />
                </UpdateParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But when I click the `Edit` link of a specific records of the GridView and make some changes, then I click the `Update` link but the changes is not reflected and it seems that it does not update into the table. (The `Edit` link look exactly like the one show in the following picture)

[image]

What could I be missing?

Comment: I might be missing something (as I have limited experience with GridViews) but your insert statement doesn't look correct to me. Shouldn't all the values be parameters, rather than just the first? I know that is the insert rather than the update, but maybe it's a knock-on effect

Comment: Also, it might be a typo on your SO question, but your datasource on the GridView is `SqlDataSource1` but the name of the source you've provided is `SqlDataSource2`

Comment: its better let visual studio make the grid for you. You have many errors on parametric, and on insert you have forget many '@`

Comment: problem seems with your insert statement...@is missing..

Comment: @freefaller Thanks for the note. I have re-copy the whole code again.

Comment: @MayankPathak. Even I changed it to `InsertCommand="INSERT INTO testtable(product_name, price, expire_date, expire_time) VALUES (@product_name, @price, @expire_date, @expire_time)" `, I still could not get the update working. (The changes have been reflected into the question)

Comment: @Aristos I wish to have Visual Studio help me to make the grid but the `Generate Insert, Update, and delete statements` is also greyed out and I can't even check the checkbox. Maybe I am really missing too much of "something"

Comment: I think as I see your code, that you do not have set a `KeyID` to your database, so visual studio did not know how to select a row. Place a `Key` on your table and it will work. Is this the key -> `product_no`?, GridView must know about it. Rebuild it with just select the table and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout these links hope it helps you

- [Insert , Update, Delete using SQLDataSource](http://www.aspdotnetfaq.com/Faq/How-to-insert-row-in-GridView-with-SqlDataSource.aspx)
- [on Asp.net Blogs](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

Comment: Could you please post some snippets from those links that you think would help so that we can reference them in the event those links no longer exist?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "DataKeyNames" in the GridView control.

Modify your gridView tag as follow:

```
 <asp:GridView DataKeyNames="product_no"   ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing these two

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="product_no" HeaderText="product_no" 
                    InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="product_no" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="product_name" HeaderText="product_name" 
                    SortExpression="product_name" />
```

with this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="product_name" SortExpression="product_name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField id="hfProduct_No" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("product_no") %>' />
        <asp:Label id="lblProduct_name" runat="server"  Text ='<%#Bind("product_name")%>' ></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField id="hfProduct_No" runat="server" value='<%# Bind("product_no") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox id="txtProduct_name" runat="server"  Text ='<%#Bind("product_name")%>' ></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>    
</asp:TemplateField>
```